# Proof of satisfiability of CNF

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I need to prove that if formula **F** in **CNF** form is satisfiable, then any subset of **CNF** which belongs to **F** must be satisfiable. I know that **CNF** is basically conjoined sets of disjunctions so from definition it is kind of obvious that if whole formula in **CNF** is satisfiable, then any subset will definitely be satisfiable as well because any subset will have an interpretation which will be True. However, I am not sure how to start to prove it formally.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it *is* kind of obvious ... to make it hard, I would say: if $F$ is satisfiable, then that means that there is some truth-value assignment that sets all of the conjuncts of its CNF to true. So, that verysame truth-value assignment will certainly set any subset of those conjuncts to true, meaning that that set is satisfiable.

Comment: Is there any way to show that subset is satisfiable via induction or other way but more formally?

Comment: @Augustas Not sure how induction would help with this .... I think what I wrote is a perfectly acceptable proof. Maybe if the porblem statement was given more formally itself, but it isn't so I think this is the 'appropriate' level of detail.